# Event delegation in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Well I am not sure how should it be so I suppose , it can be achieved via event delegation.

In my project , There is a side bar that is named 'Accordion'. Now all the related JS files , is in a separate `plugin folder` named `AccordionPlugin`.

And , inside this `Accrdn_ui.js` file, there is a function that I need. It makes a call to `Accrdn_Ctrl` and returns me some count.

**But initially , the function GetEntityCount() parameter value is empty. So , the function throws exception.**

```
Accordion.AccordionViewModel = WebUI.BaseViewModel.inherits({
initializeViewModel: function (options) {

    this.bindAll('onItemSelect');
    this.initializeBinding(options);
},
initializeBinding: function (options) {
    this.model = new Accordion.AccordionModel();
    this.id = options.id;
    this.mode = options.mode;
    this.getAccordionItems(function () {
        this.getEntityCount();
    });
},

getEntityCount: function () {

    //this.postDataRequest('/GetEntityCount', { id: this.id, mode: this.mode }, function (err, result) {

    this.postDataRequest('/GetEntityCount', { id: $("#siteId").text(), mode: this.mode }, function (err, result) { //$("#siteId").text() -- for now is empty text
        if (!err && result && result.success) {
            this.model.setCount(result.data);
        }

    });
},

......
```

This `$("#siteId").text()` gets set in another plugin and another JS file viewmodel.

```
function removepage() {
    debugger;
    .......
    .......
    $("#siteName").append(tempSite);
    $("#siteId").append(siteIdVal);

    if ($("#area-view").is(":visible")) {
        $("#area-view").hide();
    } else {
        $("#area-view").show();
    }
    ......
    ......
}
```

How would it notify the function() about it . SO that it gets picked up ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by arranging the execution order of view models' code. You probably need a deferred object to do this synchronization task.

Firstly, in place of initialization JS (your JS controller or something) where you instantiate AccordionViewModel and site view model, create a deferred and pass it to both of the view model constructors:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var accordion = new Accordion.AccordionViewModel($.extend(options, {deferred: deferred}));
var site = new SiteViewModel($.extend(options, {deferred: deferred}));
```

Next, you'll want to set deferred state as finished in the function removepage of site view model:

```
function removepage() {
    debugger;
    .......
    .......
    $("#siteName").append(tempSite);
    $("#siteId").append(siteIdVal);

    //sets deferred object passed from view model constructor to finished
    this.deferred.resolve(siteIdVal);

    if ($("#area-view").is(":visible")) {
        $("#area-view").hide();
    } else {
        $("#area-view").show();
    }
    ......
    ......
}
```

In that way, code which is attached in deferred callback queue will be executed when it's done:

```
Accordion.AccordionViewModel = WebUI.BaseViewModel.inherits({
initializeViewModel: function (options) {

    this.bindAll('onItemSelect');
    this.initializeBinding(options);
},
initializeBinding: function (options) {
    this.model = new Accordion.AccordionModel();
    this.id = options.id;
    this.mode = options.mode;
    var that = this;
    options.deferred.done(function(siteId){
        that.getAccordionItems($.proxy(function () {
            this.getEntityCount(siteId);
        }, that));
    });
},

getEntityCount: function (siteId) {

    //this.postDataRequest('/GetEntityCount', { id: this.id, mode: this.mode }, function (err, result) {

    this.postDataRequest('/GetEntityCount', { id: siteId, mode: this.mode }, function (err, result) { //$("#siteId").text() -- for now is empty text
        if (!err && result && result.success) {
            this.model.setCount(result.data);
        }

    });
},
```